# Sending an image from a server to client using HTTP in python

Tags: python, http, client-server

I was creating a web server that process client requests and send data through HTTP. I used python and it works perfectly for text, pdf and html files. When I tried to send a jpg image by this server, the client shows that, the image cant displayed because it contain errors in the client. I used different approaches given in this site, but failed. Can someone help me?? Image sending part of the code is given below. Thanks in advance...

```
req = clnt.recv(102400)
a = req.split('\n')[0].split()[1].split('/')[1]
if a.split('.')[1] == 'jpg':
    path =  os.path.abspath(a)
    size = os.path.getsize(path)
    img_file = open(a, 'rb') 
    bytes_read = 0
    while bytes_read < size:
        strng = img_file.read(1024)
        if not strng:
            break
        bytes_read += len(strng)
    clnt.sendall('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n' + 'Content-type: image/jpeg"\n\n' + strng)
    clnt.close()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: You could always base64 encode your image, send that to the server and then decode it. It's how I usually handle image transfers over HTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the string each time you perform a read on the file. If the file is greater than 1024 bytes you will lose the previously read chunk. Eventually the last read will return an empty string at EOF so `strng` will end up being the empty string.

```
strng = img_file.read(1024)
```

I think that you meant to use `+=`?:

```
strng += img_file.read(1024)
```

There is not really any advantage to reading the file in chunks like this. Reading all the file contents in one read will consume the same amount of memory. You could do this instead:

```
if a.split('.')[1] == 'jpg':
    path =  os.path.abspath(a)
    with open(a, 'rb') as img_file:
        clnt.sendall('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n' + 'Content-type: image/jpeg"\n\n' + img_file.read())
    clnt.close()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Also, strictly speaking those `\n` characters should be `\r\n` for HTTP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It worked well, but a little more issues and I'll sort it out...